# Why does division by zero still produce a resultset?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am using sql server 2012

This is my query:

```
begin try 
select 1/0 
end try
begin catch
select 'div by 0'
end catch
```

It returns 2 different results:

[image]

but the result expected is `div by 0` ? because the control after the failure of try is transferred to catch?

So why does it return 2 results?

Comment: You have 2 selects, that's why also 2 result sets

Answer (score 3):

The significant thing here is that divison by zero is a runtime error and *terminates the statement* at the point it has reached. The statement `select 1/0` is perfectly valid in itself and the resultset can be created, it's during the evaluation of the expression `1/0` for the first and only row of data that the error occurs. If you extend your example a little you will see this better;

```
begin try 
declare @t table (i float)
insert @t values (2),(1),(0),(-1)
select 1/i as r from @t 
end try
begin catch
select 'div by 0'
end catch
```

In the first resultset produced you will now see 2 rows, then the division by zero occurs and no further rows are produced. What is interesting to note though is the 'rows affected' messages.

```
(4 row(s) affected)

(0 row(s) affected)

(1 row(s) affected)
```

The 4 row(s) are from `insert @t` and the 1 row(s) is from the `select 'div by 0'`. The terminated `select 1/i as r from @t` reports 0 row(s), despite the fact that we can see 2 rows were returned to SSMS. What is happening here is that although the resultset is created and rows are returned to the client, the SQL Server database engine supports the [ACID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480356.aspx) properties, and because the `select 1/i as r from @t` did not complete fully it is rolled back (the select is being atomic). SSMS may have received some rows, but as far as SQL Server is concerned no rows were produced. Extending your example again to capture the rows demonstrates this;

```
declare @t table (i float)
declare @t2 table (i float)
insert @t values (2),(1),(0),(-1)
begin try 
insert @t2 select 1/i as r from @t 
end try
begin catch
select 'div by 0'
end catch
select * from @t2
```

When this is run you will see that @t2 contains no rows.

If you want to read up further on SQL Server's behaviour when division by zero occurs see [ARITHABORT, ARITHIGNORE and ANSI_WARNINGS](http://www.sommarskog.se/error-handling-I.html#ANSI_WARNINGS) in Erland Sommarskog's error handling document.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It will show two results. It can be solved in two ways

**1. Using with stored procedure**

If you want to show result based on `TRY` and `CATCH`, try using an `OUT` parameter for returning result

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcedureName   
   @RESULT VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
   begin try 
      select @RESULT = 1/0           
   end try
   begin catch
     select @RESULT = 'div by 0'         
   end catch

select @RESULT
END
```

**2. Using without stored procedure**

Declare a variable that holds the result based on `TRY` and `CATCH`

```
DECLARE @RESULT VARCHAR(100)

begin try 
  select @RESULT = 4/0           
end try
begin catch
 select @RESULT = 'div by 0'         
end catch

select @RESULT
```